# Skimage: How add more black to the top bottom and sides of a thresholded image?

Tags: python, rotation, scikit-image, image-rotation

I need to rotate an image so that it's major and minor axes are vertical and perpendicular respectively. However, every time I rotate the image it cuts off the side and bottom. How do I add an equal amount of black pixels to the top, bottom, left, and right so that it doesn't get cut anymore?

Answer (score 2):

In scikit-image, [images are just NumPy arrays](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/numpy_images.html), so to pad them, you can use [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```py
import numpy as np

padded_image = np.pad(
        image,
        np.ceil((np.hypot(*image.shape)) - image.shape)) / 2).astype(int),
        mode='constant',
        constant_values=0,
)
```

I tried to compute the smallest amount of padding that you'll need, but I'm not 100% sure that's right. If it doesn't work, have a play with the second argument to `np.pad`, `pad_width`.

I also assume 2D grayscale images above. You'll have to modify the padding a bit to deal with RGB.